# viso2 gets lost unless in fast motion

Tags: kinect, openni, viso2-ros, viso2, libviso2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I am trying to use viso2 (https://github.com/srv/viso2) for visual odometry. I have the following setup:

- Kinect camera
- Openni driver (https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni_launch)
- TF-Transform between base_link and kinect_link, so that it is in the *optical frame*
- Starting viso2 with https://github.com/ct2034/auckbot/blob/master/auckbot_navigation/launch/viso2_demo_mono.launch

The behavior that I am seeing is that most of the time the `got_lost` flag is set (in the `/mono_odometer/info` topic).
And also the pose is not updated. But when I move the camera really fast, the flag changes for one frame or so and the pose changes.

Is this a problem of setup? But there doesn't seem to be a parameter that influences this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202205/viso2-gets-lost-unless-in-fast-motion/) by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on ROS Answers with karma: 862 on 2015-02-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2015-02-11**:
Are your images rectified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For a kinect I would recommend you use [fovis](http://wiki.ros.org/fovis) VO. With it you will take advantage of the depth image and get better results than only with a monocular visual odometer.

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2015-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0